# install python-dev on kali for python2.7

Tags: python, linux

my the initial task is to install pcapy for python2.7.
But I get error

> error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

after googling, I found three basic tips on how to solve the problem:

1 ) install libffi-dev
But its already installed: libffi-dev is already the newest version (3.4.2-4)

2 ) install libpcap-dev
But its already installed: libpcap-dev is already the newest version (1.10.1-4).

3 ) install python-dev

And here I get an error:

> └─# apt-get install python2-dev
>  Reading package lists... Done
>  Building dependency tree... Done
>  Reading state information...
> Done
>  You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct
> these.
>  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> python-twisted-web : Depends: python (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is not
> installable
> Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installable
> Depends: python-twisted-core (>= 11.0) but it is not installable
>   python2-dev : Depends: libpython2-dev (=
> 2.7.18-3) but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: python2.7-dev (>= 2.7.18~) but it is not going to be installed
>  E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken
> install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Kali version:

Linux kali 5.14.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.14.16-1kali1 (2021-11-05) x86_64 GNU/Linux

if someone can suggest what else I can try to install pcapy, I will also be grateful for advice.

Comment: What output you did get after doing `apt --fix-broken install` as suggest by your error?

Comment: Thank you - its working. I tried this command  - but with wrong syntax. Again - thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tells you to perform in terminal:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

You can download pcapy from the source and install it.